# ASP Database connection questions

Tags: asp.net, database, database-connection, connection-string, webforms

I'm finding a lot of ways to connect to a MS SQL database online. I'm using the connection String in web.config. It's working perfectly fine for what we want and looks something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxx" 
         connectionString="SERVER=xxx;UID=xxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=xxx;"
      providerName="xxx" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is this the best way to connect. I'm then using it with an asp web forms application mostly using gridview

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MatchDataSource" Runat="server"

            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [xxx].[Matcxxxh]"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [xxx].[Matxxxch] SET [xxx] = 
              @xxx, [xxx] = @xxx, [xxx] = 
              @xxx WHERE x=@xxxAnd x=@xxx"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxx %>">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="CSISN"/>
                <asp:Parameter Type="String"  Name="ProcName"/>

            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="MatchDataSource" Width="100%">
            <RowStyle BackColor="white" ForeColor="black" Font-Italic="false" BorderColor="Black" />


            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="xxx" HeaderText="xxx">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="editxxx" Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("xxx") %>' 
                            MaxLength="15" ToolTip="Enter CSI SN"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" Runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must provide a xxx." ControlToValidate="editxxx">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CSISN") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

My questions are

1. Am I going about this correctly?
2. Can anyone point me to a proper tutorial which will show best practices?
3. How do i close the connection at the end when the script finishes running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is *one* of many ways to use connection strings from configuration. There is nothing wrong with it. Looks fine.
2. No, as this is a subjective thing and not the kind of thing we answer here.
3. The connection will close when the script finishes. You don't need to do anything (`SqlDataSource` takes care of all the details).

Answer (score 0):

I would agrue against using a SqlDataSource.

Yes, it works well on that page. However if the call needs to be used another page you end up copying and pasting things over to get it to work there.

I would recommend creating some sort of class that makes the call to the database and returns it as a List or an IEnumerable. Then using that class you can assign the data source in the code behind.

The following is a small example which uses the entity framework to query the data.

---

Data Access Class

```
public static class DataAccess
{
    public static List<Section> GetDataFromDatabase()
    {
        List<Section> recordList;
        using (CustomEntities context = new CustomEntities())
        {

            IQueryable<Section> query = from records in context.Records
                                                 select sections;
            recordList= query.ToList<Record>();
        }
        return recordList;
    }
}
```

---

Code-behind usage

```
    private void BindLists()
    {
        // Get the data
        List<Section> theData = DataAccess.GetDataFromDatabase();

        // Assign the data source
        gridView.DataSource = theData;

        // Bind the grid view
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
```

---

This way provides more reuse across your application, and makes changes a lot easier.